# Can you explain with examples what exactly is mathematical modeling to a person that is not very good with math?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Please explain with examples what exactly is mathematical modeling to a person that is not very good with math.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHtsuOB-TPw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest kind of model can be a single equation. For example, a linear equation that roughly describes the relationship between the age of the population (say from 0 to 18) and average height. You input an age into the model and the average height for that age is the output.

There are many more models which are extremely complex but the principle is the same. Example: An aircraft structural model. Input flights loads into the model and the output is the individual loads in the structural members (frames, floor beams, wing spars etc). Engineers can then design these members to withstand the loads they carry.

Comment: So computer simulation of aircraft structural model is a mathematical model of that aircraft?

Comment: Yes, mathematical in both a geometric representation of the structure and also in carrying the physical properties of each structural member. That is, the modulus of the material they are to be made from, their stiffness, and end fixity, You may have heard of the term "finite element analysis", well this is the kind of model they use to analyze the stresses and deflections of the structure.